# Html5 with CSS elements move when zooming

Tags: css, html, css-position

Hi guys this might be a easy question but I'm struggling a bit with this one problem in my HTML and CSS page.

Problem: When i zoom int the "Section" part moves under the nav and when i zoom out the footer moves next to the section part.....

Here is the sample of my HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MyWebsite</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<header>
   Header
  </header>


<body>



  <nav>
      <ul>
          <li>
             Tab1 
          </li>
          <li>
            Tab2 
          </li>
          <li>
             Tab3 
          </li>
          <li>
             Tab4 
          </li>
          <li>
             Tab5
          </li>


      </ul>
  </nav>



  <section id="">
 Section
  </section>

  <footer>
  Footer
  </footer>



</body>


</html>`
```

here is the CSS page:

```
header
{
    width: 1325px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
}

nav
{
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height:  500px;
    background-color: teal;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

section
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 925px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: blue;
}

footer
{
      float: left;
    width: 1325px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: lime;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;    
}
```

thanks for your help and time in advance

Comment: Just a quick note before I check your problem. You're syntax on the `ul` and `li` is wrong. `li` is a child of `ul` not a parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `body` tag needs to be before the header. Add a wrapper with a width to your HTML/CSS.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/msJLW/

```
<div id="wrap">
<header>
   Header
  </header>
  <nav>
      <ul>
          <li>
             Tab1 
          </li>
          <li>
            Tab2 
          </li>
          <li>
             Tab3 
          </li>
          <li>
             Tab4 
          </li>
          <li>
             Tab5
          </li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
  <section id="">
 Section
  </section>

  <footer>
  Footer
  </footer>

</div>

#wrap{
    width:1325px;
}
header
{
    width: 1325px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: green;

}

nav
{
    width: 400px;
    height:  500px;
    background-color: teal;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

section
{
    float: left;
    width: 925px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: blue;
}

footer
{
      float: left;
    width: 1325px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: lime;
    overflow: hidden;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Jack is correct, and you might want to try adding a container to your elements. See this fiddle: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9CZHM/). Essentially, they are all

```
position: relative
```

without having an absolutely positioned container to refer to. Adding a wrapping container with the CSS:

```
position: absolute;
height: 700px;
width: 1325px;
```

Kept everything in line. Let me know if this wasn't what you were trying to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why it is moving like this, but I know a simple solution: contain it all in a wrapper. Copy/paste this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MyWebsite</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      Header
    </header>
     <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>Tab 1</li>
        <li>Tab 2</li>
        <li>Tab 3</li>
        <li>Tab 4</li>
        <li>Tab 5</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <section id="">
      Section
    </section>
    <footer>
      Footer
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Keep in mind that anything not included in the <head> tags should be inside the <body> tags, except your doctype and <html> tags -- this includes your <header> tags.

Anyway, what we've done above is wrap everything in a "div", a means by which we can divide a web page up. They are easy to control using css, and you should copy/paste the following to the bottom of your css file:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 1325px;
}
```

Let me know if you need any more help :D